# Serve the content of many files from a unique URL in php

Tags: php, file, url, join

Using php, I'm trying to "join without joining" some .flac files that my audio device could read (via upnp) from a unique url. The easy way should be to create a new flac file, but I'd rather not, because it spends a lot of resources (that my rpi server doesn't have).

My idea was to scan the whole directory, and then open each files one after the other, but that just dosent work.

```
<?
$directory = '/path/to/my/directory/with/flac/files';
$scanned_directory = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('..', '.'));

foreach ($scanned_directory as $key => $value) {

   echo file_get_contents($value);

} 
?>
```

I think I'm missing something important as to handling files and streams.

Any idea how I should do it ?

Comment: What does _**"but that just dosent work"**_ means? what is the problem you are facing? Right now your script does not make sense. Do you need it to provide clients with an audio stream ? Would not it be much better to provide client with playlist and client would fetch audio files individually as static files without php?